# Tools for automated benchmark testing of Java apps?

Tags: java, testing, benchmarking

Does anyone know of any tools for automated benchmark testing of Java applications?

By benchmark testing, I mean comparison of results to previous results and/or presenting results along a continuum of bad-to-good rather than pass/fail.

Comment: What type of "benchmark" testing? Performance, acceptance, unit?

Comment: there seem to be lots of other threads on this, such as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260338/java-benchmarking-tool

Answer (score 0):

If your IDE is eclipe, then ofcourse TPTPT is the thing, but I am not sure about how much of the stuff you can automate.

But then you aslo have [Faban](http://faban.sunsource.net/) which is a "harness to automate running of server benchmarks as well as a container to host benchmarks allowing new benchmarks to be deployed .."