# multiple method call with or without explicit variable

Tags: java

I believe this could be a `premature optimization` problem or something else.

For following two code snippets,

```java
public void doSomething1(final int a) {
    final int b = a -1;
    doSomethingElse(b);
    doSomethingElse(b);
}

public void doSomething2(final int a) {
    doSomethingElse(a - 1);
    doSomethingElse(a - 1);
}
```

Is `doSomething1` is better than `doSomething2`? Does `doSomething2` uses two different `int`s?

**UPDATE**

Maybe I deserve down votes. But I have an actual code which reads and writes variable-length bits (not bytes) like this.

```java
final int unsignedLength = length - 1;

return (((readBoolean() ? ~0 : 0) << (length - 1))
        | readUnsignedInt(length - 1));
```

I was just curious for changing `(length - 1)` part with `unsignedLength`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking whether `doSomething1` is better than `doSomething2` or are you stating it and asking for an explanation?

Comment: Actually I wanna know which one is preferable. Thank you.

Comment: If the calculation of `b` is more complicated you should use `doSomething1`. Otherwise the compiler will take care with high probability. You should use what is more easy to maintain in the specific case.

Comment: if you could explain what you mean by "better"? If you are saying in terms of memory allocation then the second method is better,because of no additional variable as in first method `final int b`. The execution time should typically be the same for both the methods.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894629/performance-by-creating-new-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally completely overkill to try and optimize on this level as the difference it's going to make on your application is so tiny. `doSomething1` should be the more efficient one as it doesn't need to calculate `a - 1` twice. This sort of thing is may be optimized by the compiler however.

Regardless you should go for `doSomething1` as it's easier to maintain, even though it has more code there is only one place where the calculation `a - 1` is taking place. This makes it less likely to make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void doSomething1(final int a) {
    final int b = a -1;
    doSomethingElse(b);
    doSomethingElse(b);
}

public void doSomething2(final int a) {
    doSomethingElse(a - 1);
    doSomethingElse(a - 1);
}
```

Whilst I believe that it's not a big issue, `doSomething1` is more efficient than `doSomething2`.  As you stated, this does seem to be a premature optimization issue.  Why compute `a-1` multiple times?  It seems insignificant, but these small things add up.  So long as efficiency is more important that memory allocation, then you have your answer, I believe.  Obviously this is a trivial example, but `doSomething1` is definitely preferable to `doSomething2` efficiency-wise.

Answer (score 1):

`doSomething1()` uses an extra variable `b` where doSomething2() does not create an extra variable. If you see one point then doSomething1() performs operation `a-1` only once, but doSomething2() performs twice. Here's what i think, but i am  not sure about which oen is better.

Comment: You just mentioned what exactly I wanted to know. `variable assignment` and `operation`

Answer (score 1):

> Is doSomething1 better than doSomething2?

It is slightly better even in this simple example but not in terms of performance, but in terms of maintainability, as you dont have duplicate code (a - 1) at multiple places.

> Does doSomething2 uses two different ints?

no it is same in both cases

Also as said it is premature optimization and shouldn't be focused on.

In performance wise also I dont think there is any difference even in the stightest bit as a is declared as final and the expression of either b or a-1 will evaluate to a constant after compilation.