# Java Benchmarking

Tags: java, open-source, benchmarking

We are doing benchmarking for Perl,Php, Python interpreters using there standard benchmark tools like perlbench,pybench and php bench.

Now we need to benchmark JAVA and found "OLIO" kit would  help. But seems OLIO supports php and rails.

Please suggest me some of the best benchmarking tools for JAVA which is open source.
Jmeter is the one we know which is used for load testing.

thank you..

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260338/java-benchmarking-tool?rq=1) provide several suggestions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SpecJbb for evaluating performance of server side java - http://www.spec.org/jbb2005/
SpecJVM for evaluating performance of the JRE - http://www.spec.org/jvm2008/

**MicroBenchmark**
JMH - http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/
Google Caliper - https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks

**Load Testing**
Apache Jmeter - http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html

**CPU, Memory Profiling**
Yourkit - http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp
VisualVM - http://visualvm.java.net/

Comment: the [DaCapo Benchmark Suite](http://dacapobench.org/)