# Looping through 2d array. Performance question

Tags: java, arrays, performance, runtime

Why is below uncommented code much faster than the commented out code? Leetcode beginner here, and I honestly don't see the difference between the two.

```java
class Solution {
    //public int maximumWealth(int[][] accounts) {
    //    int max = 0;
    //    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
    //        int sum = 0;
    //        for (int j = 0; j < accounts[i].length; j++) {
    //            sum += accounts[i][j];
    //        }
    //        max = Integer.max(max, sum);
    //    }
    //    return max;
    //}
    public int maximumWealth(int[][] accounts) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int[] account : accounts) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < account.length; j++) {
                sum += account[j];
            }
            max = Integer.max(max, sum);
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is faster?  (It probably isn't, but it's easy to measure it in an incorrect way that makes you think it is.)

Comment: To the people trying to turn ^^^ into a credible benchmark ... use JMH or Caliper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15199328/139985

Answer (score 3):

### Difference

In your first method `maximumWealth(int[][] acounts` you use in the **inner** and in the **outer loop** a **traditional for-loop** while against in the second method you use in the **outer loop** an **enhanced for-loop**

```
 for (int[] account : accounts)
```

---

### Experiment

Experiment to measure the runtime.

1. Created 21 arrays inside of the accounts array
2. loop through it with the two distinct maximumWealth(int[][] acounts)

- in the first we use the enhanced for-loop
- in the second we use the traditional for-loop

3. stop the time beeing passed for executing in nanoseconds.
4. do step 3 ten times and calculate the average
5. compare the averages in nanoseconds

### Which loop is faster?

**Enhanced for-loop**

```java
public class Tryout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] accounts = {{3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 31, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                {2, 3, 3, 3, 33, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 33, 32, 2, 21, 1, 1, 22, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {5, 0, 2, 92, 31},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int result = Tryout.maximumWealthEnhanced(accounts);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(totalTime);
    }

    public static int maximumWealthEnhanced(int[][] accounts) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int[] account : accounts) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < account.length; j++) {
                sum += account[j];
            }
            max = Integer.max(max, sum);
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

**Runtime AVG**

```
1. 37085 NS
2. 41154 NS
3. 47630 NS
4. 37348 NS
5. 39489 NS
6. 37107 NS
7. 37605 NS
8. 37096 NS
9. 37609 NS
10. 39255 NS
```

**AVG** = 39137,0 Nanoseconds

**Traditional for loop**

```java
public class Tryout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] accounts = {{3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 31, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                {2, 3, 3, 3, 33, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 33, 32, 2, 21, 1, 1, 22, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {5, 0, 2, 92, 31},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {92, 92, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int result = Tryout.maximumWealth(accounts);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(totalTime);
    }

    public static int maximumWealth(int[][] accounts) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < accounts[i].length; j++) {
                sum += accounts[i][j];
            }
            max = Integer.max(max, sum);
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

**Runtime AVG**

```
1. 43645 NS
2. 42052 NS
3. 40661 NS
4. 40936 NS
5. 46346 NS
6. 46916 NS
7. 42064 NS
8. 39406 NS
9. 39572 NS
10. 40945 NS
```

**AVG** = 42254,3 Nanoseconds

---

### Conclusion

So I wouldn't say the enhanced is much faster. I would say it is a tiny nano seconds bit faster.

An important thing to note here is the enhanced for loop uses an Iterator, so if you manually iterate over a collection using an Iterator then you should have pretty much the same performance.

Benefits of the enhanced for loop are it's convenient and less error-prone, but if you want more control over iteration process then use traditional for loop.

Resources:

1. [Difference between for loop and Enhanced for loop in Java](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/01/difference-between-for-loop-and-enhanced-forlop-in-java.html#axzz6iTTweW00)
2. [Why is the enhanced for loop more efficient than the normal for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555418/why-is-the-enhanced-for-loop-more-efficient-than-the-normal-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

#### Conduct an experiment

Take a 2d array of `30000x30000` random elements. Prepare three methods for benchmarking and call each of them 20 times, measure the time and calculate the average.

**Results:** an *enhanced for loop* is faster then a regular *for loop*, and a *parallel stream* is two times faster.

```
   enhanced for: avg 750 ms
       for loop: avg 1013 ms
parallel stream: avg 385 ms
```

**Best result:** parallel stream

```
public static int maximumWealthPStream(int[][] accounts) {
    return Arrays.stream(accounts).parallel()
            .mapToInt(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).sum())
            .max().orElse(0);
}
```

---

Full results:

```
   enhanced for: 1281 | 1286 |  701 |  710 |  690 |  691 |  702 |  688 |  689 |  676 |  673 |  705 |  698 |  686 |  686 |  688 |  684 |  683 |  690 |  696 || avg 750 ms
       for loop:  669 |  667 | 1252 |  677 |  670 |  659 |  669 |  652 |  657 | 1226 | 1240 | 1244 | 1279 | 1230 | 1218 | 1224 | 1260 | 1233 | 1289 | 1260 || avg 1013 ms
parallel stream:  455 |  378 |  376 |  380 |  377 |  372 |  376 |  371 |  374 |  376 |  369 |  372 |  382 |  379 |  375 |  370 |  369 |  376 |  516 |  376 || avg 385 ms
```

Code of experiment:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 30000;
    int count = 20;

    // random array
    int[][] arr = IntStream.range(0, size)
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, size)
                    .map(j -> (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10))
                    .toArray())
            .toArray(int[][]::new);

    benchmark("enhanced for", count, () -> maximumWealthEnhanced(arr));
    benchmark("for loop", count, () -> maximumWealthFor(arr));
    benchmark("parallel stream", count, () -> maximumWealthPStream(arr));
}
```

```java
public static void benchmark(String name, int count, Runnable runnable) {
    int average = 0;
    System.out.print(String.format("%16s", name + ":"));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        runnable.run();
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.print(" " + String.format("%4d", time) + " |");
        average += time;
    }
    average /= count;
    System.out.println("| avg " + average + " ms");
}
```

```java
public static int maximumWealthEnhanced(int[][] accounts) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int[] account : accounts) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < account.length; j++) {
            sum += account[j];
        }
        max = Integer.max(max, sum);
    }
    return max;
}
```

```java
public static int maximumWealthFor(int[][] accounts) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < accounts[i].length; j++) {
            sum += accounts[i][j];
        }
        max = Integer.max(max, sum);
    }
    return max;
}
```

```java
public static int maximumWealthPStream(int[][] accounts) {
    return Arrays.stream(accounts).parallel()
            .mapToInt(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).sum())
            .max().orElse(0);
}
```